# Handling n-n relationships in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple BOM database model and using Model First to map and use it in EF.The problem with it is,i have a N-N table,and i just can not add more than 1 item to it.
[image: DB]

For example in Kartela table, i can add multiple items from KartelaMalkodlari table since it's a 1-n relationship.

```
        KartelaMalkodlari _malkodlari = new KartelaMalkodlari();
        _malkodlari.MalKodu = "Walalala";

        KartelaMalkodlari _malkodlari2 = new KartelaMalkodlari();
        _malkodlari2.MalKodu = "Holowowlwo";



        Kartela _kartela = new Kartela();
        _kartela.KartelaMalkodlari.Add(_malkodlari);
        _kartela.KartelaMalkodlari.Add(_malkodlari2);
```

..so on.

But since my KartelaBOM table holds n-n relationships,i just can not add multiple items to it.How does EF handle n-n relationships and whats the way to achieve it?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I dont get any errors.Its jsut the model.It wont allow me to add multiple entities using KartelaBOm.Kartelabomitems.add() etc...

Comment: Now your KartelaBOM can have only one KartelaBOMItems.. You need row_id of KartelaBOM as a column in KartelaBOMItems table, remove BOMItems_ID from KaretalaBOM and reverse the foreign key.

Comment: Hmm just did a little more research and found out that n-n tables should not have columns other than the relationship IDs and both must be primary keys.Interesting.